Odd string in output ̄[2000/12/14 v1.0] in tufte style
I am writing a book using Tufte style but i keep on getting the string

as the first page. I tried to troubleshoot but unsuccessfully. Could you help? I attach my code:
       \documentclass[symmetric,justified,nobib, notoc]{tufte-book}


\usepackage[polutonikogreek,italian]{babel}%lingue usate. L'ultima è quella principale.
\newcommand{\greco}[1]{\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}%passare da ita a greco.



\usepackage{pxfonts}%tutti simboli matematici.


\usepackage{teubner}


\usepackage{devanagari}%per il sanscrito



\begin{document}

\maketitle

Ciao.


\end{document}

It must be caused by some package but i cannot see which one. Thank you!!
UPDATE: i edited with the MWE that seems to reproduce the feature. In particular it is the set of packages
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath, amsthm,marvosym,wasysym,pxfonts,cancel}

\usepackage{teubner}

\usepackage{devanagari}

That seems to generate this string.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{pxfonts}

\usepackage{teubner}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}


It's unrelated to the tufte class, I added a more reasonable example.

teubner and devanagari seem to be incompatible. It works, if I remove one of them.

Yes! you nailed it. Thank you a lot... i was getting mad trying to understand the problem in tufte but it is uncorrelated.

The dates are from the pxfont fd files

The fd files for px fonts start
\ProvidesFile{ot1pxr.fd}
    [2000/12/14 v1.0]

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pxr}{\hyphenchar\font45 }

where the white space before the [2000 is a tab character.
That should be fine and tab normally has catcode 10 so is treated like a space but...
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{pxfonts}

\showthe\catcode9
\usepackage{teubner}

\showthe\catcode9
\usepackage{devanagari}

\showthe\catcode9
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}

produces
...
> 10.
l.10 \showthe\catcode9
                      
? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/velthuis/devanagari.sty)
> 11.
l.13 \showthe\catcode9
                      
? 

so after devanagari tab is catcode 11, a normal letter.
This means that
\ProvidesFile{ot1pxr.fd}

is followed by a normal letter, not an optional argument and
<tab>[2000/12/14 v1.0]

Is just plain text and gets typeset as such producing

For the three fd files input.
devanangari leaving tab catcode 11 looks like a bug to me, you could reportt that, but anyway putting
\catcode9=10

after
\usepackage{devanagari}

will work around it.

Actually, as soon as i posted i finally realized it is the \usepackage{devanagari} package that is causing the trouble but i have no clue on why is this...

It's a problem with category codes. However we see in the devanagari.sty file
% We execute the macro straight away, which means these catcodes are in
% force throughout the whole document, not just in the Devanagari part
% of the text.  This can sometimes cause spurious "Omega" characters if,
% in some special conditions, TeX reads a line feed outside the \dn
% environment, and so forth.
%
% The alternative, i.e., calling the catcodes locally within Devanagari
% text, leads to even worse "illegal character" problems with \chapter
% and \section headings, etc. This dilemma may be soluble in the longer
% run, but is not being addressed in the current release (2004).
% This is, however, in conflict with MusixTeX. Option "nocatcodes" will
% execute the macro only within Devanagari text.
%
% Version 2.02 of the preprocessor was redesigned so that the catcodes
% need not be changed. The change of catcodes may be, however, in rare
% cases necessary (see the manual for details). In such cases you can
% use the "catcodes" option. Option "compat" enters the compatibility
% mode which changes the catcodes within \dn as in the old version.

You can simply call the package with the nocatcodes option.
Also, pxfonts is not the best package to get Palatino (kerning is very awkward) and I suggest NewPX.
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,nobib, notoc]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,italian]{babel}%lingue usate. L'ultima è quella principale.
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}%tutti simboli matematici.
\usepackage{teubner}
\usepackage[nocatcodes]{devanagari}%per il sanscrito

\newcommand{\greco}[1]{\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}%passare da ita a greco.

\begin{document}

Ciao.

\end{document}

Actually, with newpxtext and newpxmath the problem doesn't show, but it could with other packages, so I recommend nocatcodes anyway.
